# Different margin on layout and on emulator in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am learning to develop apps in android studio, and I am having some issues regarding the layout I am creating for my aps. I have 3x3 grid layout, and in each grid I placed an ImageView. Then I played around with margins to set up my app, however when it is displayed on the emulator, the margins are not in the places I put them. Here is a picture of my problem:

[image]

Why is this happening, and could someone help me in solving this?

Comment: can you show your xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout editor you have the nexus 4 selected as the device for the screen size. You did not provide your layout code but I assume everything you did is static.
If your emulator is emulating another phone (a Nexus 5) with a different resolution and dpi, that could be the reason for the different layout.

Comment: The window title does say Nexus 5